# when two associations are equal?

Tags: associations, expression-test, language-design

`<|a -> 2, b -> 3|> == <|b -> 3, a -> 2|>` returns `False`; can anybody explain why? If I am not mistaken here these two associations would be identical from the practical point of view.

Comment: The developers of Mathematica do not agree with you, or they would have given Association the [Orderless](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) property. With this property those two associations would indeed be equal. You can use Attributes[Association] to confirm that Association does not have that property. Maybe someone knows why this is, let's see.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed I was tried to mimic what Options do, which seems to be not caring of the order they are given.

Comment: @Roberto The order of options do matter in the sense that earlier options will override later options.  This is actually the reverse of associations where later entries override earlier ones.  I am not sure what you are attempting but be careful.

Comment: It's true that if you write `a->something` many times you might not realizing that later you are overwriting your assignment, but isn't it the same for variable assignment with `=`? I mean `a=2; b=3; a=something` is the same as `<| a->2, b->3, a->something |>` ... right?

Comment: ... and yes, you wondered correctly that I am trying to use Association and Options to set a large number of variables end evaluate functions on these large dimensional domains in a way that does not require to put arguments in a too restricting form.

Comment: This is indeed a deliberate design decision. There is an undocumented version of `Association` that does not care about order: `Data\`UnorderedAssociation`.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps as Pickett describes the developers do not consider these associations `Equal` since that function performs other conversions like:

```
Quantity[5, "Percent"] == 0.05
```

> ```
> True
> ```

But perhaps `Equal` has not been (properly?) extended to associations yet as `2.0` and `2` are `Equal` but these are not:

```
<|a -> 2|> == <|a -> 2.0|>
```

> ```
> False
> ```

---

Depending on what you are doing this might be useful, but beware it does not have early exit (short-circuit) behavior:

```
eq[{x_}] = False;
eq[{x__}] := Equal[x]

one = <|a -> 2, b -> 3|>;
two = <|b -> 3, a -> 2.0|>;

And @@ Merge[{one, two}, eq]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed investigation of the fact. I think that `<|a -> 2|> == <|a -> 2.0|>` being `False` points towards a bug, rather than a feature.